# Excel ActiveX textbox - count characters or change case

Tags: vba, excel, textbox, barcode

Two days of continual failure. I am using a barcode system which has a barcode scanner which scans a barcode of alpha-numeric text and places it into an ActiveX textbox. It enters the text one letter at a time, and upon the completion of the entire barcode, it matches up to a Case selection, which then deletes the text in the box to get ready for the next scan.

The issue I happen to be facing is inside of the textbox. For whatever reason, the text goes into the textbox and occasionally ~ (1 time in one hour or 0 times in 8 hours) it will not complete the case. The exact text inside of the textbox which matches one of the cases is not counted and stays inside the box. At this point, any future scans are appended to the end of the text inside of the box.

Below is a sample of the variables, a case, and one of the events occuring based on case selection.

Variables

```
    Private Sub TextBox1_Change()


Dim ws As Worksheet, v, n, t, b, c, e, f, h, j, k, i1, i2, i3, i4
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

v = TextBox1.Value
n = 0
t = 0
b = 0
c = 0
e = 0
f = 0
h = 0
j = 0
k = 0
i1 = 0
i2 = 0
i3 = 0
i4 = 0
```

Case

```
    Select Case v


Case "2 in x 16 ft R -1": n = 9
t = 1
b = 10
c = 1
e = 11
f = 6
g = "2 in x 16 ft"
h = 40
j = 0.296
k = 1
```

Stuff that is done based on case type

```
'n = Sets the column reference for waste - not used?
't = Sets the cutting station column to be used (1,2,3) for the sq yards, row, and column of last scanned item for each station
'b = Sets the row reference for adding cut rolls waste + regular row reference for cut rolls
'c = Sets the column reference for adding cut rolls waste + regular column refernce for cut rolls
'e = Sets the column reference for taking 1 master roll out
'f = Sets the row reference for taking 1 master roll out
'g = name of the item being used for the time stamp
'h = Number of rolls coming out of the master roll
'j = The amount of Sq yards in the cut roll (to be used for waste)
'k = Case Selection
'i1 = Count for Cutting Station 1 timestamp, row reference
'i2 = Count for Cutting Station 2 timestamp, row reference
'i3 = Count for Cutting Station 3 timestamp, row reference
'i4 = Count for Cutting Station 1 timestamp, row reference - not used in this worksheet

If k = 1 And t = 1 Then
'Cutter 1 items


    ws.Cells(1, t) = b
    ws.Cells(2, t) = c
    ws.Cells(3, t) = j
    ws.Cells(4, t) = b
    ws.Cells(5, t) = c
    ws.Cells(6, t) = f
    ws.Cells(7, t) = h


    ws.Cells(b, c) = ws.Cells(b, c) + h
    ' adding different number based on case

    ws.Cells(f, e) = ws.Cells(f, e) - 1
    ' always subtracts 1 from certain range based on case


    i1 = ws.Cells(1, 30)


    Cells(i1, 19).Value = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy AM/PM h:mm:ss")
    Cells(i1, 20).Value = g

    TextBox1.Activate
    TextBox1.Value = ""
```

Remember the text enters in one character at a time until the entire barcodes information is passed into the ActiveX textbox.

I can set a max length, but upon the max length it stays in the textbox. If I set the textbox to "", the next character in the barcode starts again and the append issue continues.

Is there a way to not have the case selection start upon the entry of each single character? Is there a way to have the textbox delete the extra information. If you set it to delete something which does not match a case, then it will delete anything entered since it puts one character in at a time.

Best regards,

Ford

Comment: Are you using `On Error Resume Next` anywhere in your code?

Comment: Com, I am not. I am relatively new to VBA logic!

Comment: It looks like you only clear the TextBox `If k = 1 And t = 1`.  My guess (without seeing the full code) is that there are some input conditions that you haven't accounted for.

Comment: I currently don't have any input conditions for deleting out information which does not match a case. This is because no matter what gets scanned into the textbox, it matches one case or another. Occasionally, the information (Even though it exactly matches a case and has worked 100's of times, just sits in the textbox and does not delete out). Is there an easy way to simply delete it out of the textbox? I am going to look at the on {on error resume next}

Comment: No, *don't* look at `On Error Resume Next`. I only asked that to find out if there was a possibility that you were ignoring an error somewhere.  What is the condition `If k = 1 And t = 1` is testing?  Based on the code above, that has to be true to clear the TextBox unless there's additional code that handles it.

Comment: Basically, every case has a "k" to run a certain condition. These can range from 1,2,3,4,5. They select a certain block of conditional code which all clear the textbox. The same goes for "t", 1,2,3,4 which shows which scanning device scanned the barcode. I have several conditional If or elseif statements which all end by clearing the textbox. So ALL barcodes are ALL linked to a condition based on "t" or "k" and they ALL clear the textbox once satisfied. Something happens to where the textbox / case selection randomly does not consider the textbox to change so it doesn't run through the cases.

Comment: Is it possible to refresh the activeX textbox upon any change? or at the end of the case selections? That may work.

Comment: That's basically what I was suggesting with my first comment. If you *always* need to clear the textbox, the code to clear it should not be conditional.

Comment: I understand. I will start looking / trying out some code to refresh the textbox every time it changes. Thank you for the help so far Com!